# Proofs about invertible linear functions

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $G\subset L(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the subset of invertible linear transformations.

a) For $H\in L(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^n)$, prove that if $||H||<1$, then the partial sum $L_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}H^k$ converges to a limit $L$ and $||L||\leq\frac{1}{1-||H||}$.

b) If $A\in L(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^n)$ satisfies $||A-I||<1$, then A is invertible and $A^{-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }H^k$ where $I-A=H$. (Hint: Show that $AL_n=H^{n+1}$)

c) Let $\varphi :G\rightarrow G$ be the inversion map $\varphi(A)=A^{-1}$. Prove that $\varphi$ is continuous at the identity I, using the previous two facts.

d) Let $A, C \in G$ and $B=A^{-1}$. We can write $C=A-K$ and $\varphi(A-K)=c^{-1}=A^{-1}(I-H)^{-1}$ where $H=BK$. Use this to prove that $\varphi$ is continuous at $A$.

[a) and b) are pretty easy but I have little ideas about c) and d). Thank you!]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

c) Let $A$ be close enough to $I$, so that $||A-I|| \lt 1$. Then you have $\phi(A)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(I-A)^k$ by b). We deduce $\phi(A)-\phi(I)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(I-A)^k$, and hence

$$
|| \phi(A)-\phi(I) || \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}||I-A||^k=\frac{||I-A||}{1-||I-A||}
$$

So $\phi$ is continuous at $I$.

d) Let $C$ be close enough to $A$, so that $||C-A|| \lt \frac{1}{||A^{-1}||}$. Then
$K=C-A$ satisfies $||K|| \leq \frac{1}{||A^{-1}||}$, and hence $||A^{-1}K|| \lt 1$. We then have

$$\phi(C)=C^{-1}=(A+K)^{-1}=(A(I+A^{-1}K))^{-1}=(I+A^{-1}K)^{-1}A^{-1}=\phi(I+A^{-1}K)A^{-1},$$ so

$$
\phi(C)-\phi(A)=\big(\phi(I+A^{-1}K)-\phi(I)\big) A^{-1}
$$

and hence

$$
|| \phi(C)-\phi(A) || \leq || A^{-1}|| || \phi(I+A^{-1}K)-\phi(I) ||
\leq || A^{-1}|| \frac{||A^{-1}K||}{1-||A^{-1}K||}
$$

by part c). So

$$
|| \phi(C)-\phi(A) || \leq || A^{-1}|| \frac{||A^{-1}|| ||K||}{1-||A^{-1}|| ||K||}
$$

and $\phi$ is therefore continous at $A$.

Comment: Two questions: 1) why C close enough to I then $||C-I||<\frac{1}{||A^{-1}||}$? Should it be C close enough to "A"?2) why can we conclude that $\phi $ is continuous at $A$ by the last inequality?

Comment: @Ian 1) : corrected, thanks. 2) When $C$ tends to $A$, the distance $||C-A||=||K||$ tends to zero, so the right-hand side tends to $0$ in the last inequality

Comment: And why by the last formula in your answer in c), we can conclude $\phi$ is continuous at I?

Comment: Same thing as in d) : when $A$ tends to $I$, the distance $||A-I||$ tends to zero, as does the right-hand-side in the last inequality in my answer to c).